# while loop and method calls while loop iteration pause until methofs finish python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop below the commented out portions are from a previous test.

My hope was that the while loop would execute the methods from top to bottom and as the methods finish the methods below would start.

My hope felt valid as when the code was not in a while loop that was what was happening. Or maybe it just seemed that way?

My point is the code is executing in such a way that my assumption above seems  wrong.

can any one please explain this to me?

```
counter = (len(cities)-1)
count = 0
while count != counter:
    setCity(cities[count])
    getApiData()
    #populateVars()
    #storeInDatabase()
    #goToNextPage()
    count +=1
storeData.createCSV(OTS.CSVname)
storeData.purgeDatabase()
```

Comment: It's too late for me so I will not explain it but you can use `for i in range(counter - count):` insted of `while count != counter:` Sorry I don't even know if you were asking for that, probably not.

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: The code does execute synchronously from top to bottom unless you have done something in particular to deviate from that behavior. Use `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` and step through using the 's' command if you want to prove it to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the array without an index:

```
for city in cities:
    setCity(city)
    getApiData()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code is indeed being run sequentially, unless there's some concurrency behind the scenes that you don't know about or aren't mentioning.

Regarding your code as it is, I think you're mistakenly subtracting 1 from `len(cities)`; and anyhow, you should just iterate directly over the cities using a `for` loop.

```
for city in cities:
    setCity(city)
    getApiData()
    # populateVars()
    # storeInDatabase()
    # goToNextPage()

storeData.createCSV(OTS.CSVname)
storeData.purgeDatabase()
```

I will update this answer if there are any changes/clarifications.

Comment: to post the code that  I am working on in a relevant way would mean a significant code for you guys to read. I am going to try this again and save you all from a hassle like that. If need be ill ask a new question. Thank you all